# jquery ui - issue with resizable image within a div

Tags: jquery-ui, resizable

When resizing an image from left (using "n","w","ne","sw" or "nw" handles),
the parent's left and top positions are not affected, leading to a faulty behavior which can be seen in the following demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8VY52/1704/.

```
<div id="draggableHelper">
    <img id="image" src="http://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />
</div>

$('#draggableHelper').draggable();
$('#image').resizable({
    handles: "n, e, s, w, ne, se, sw, nw"
});

#draggableHelper{
  border: 5px solid black
}

img{
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As shown in your Demo, if you move the "top"  handle down, the Image changes but not it's position or the parent. You may consider using the `alsoResize` option: http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-alsoResize

Comment: An alternate method is assign resizable to the parent and then set Width and Height of child to 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/hukpwa3n/

**HTML**

```
<div id="draggableHelper" style="display: inline-block">
  <img id="image" src="http://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#draggableHelper {
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  background: red;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.ui-resizable-handle {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.ui-resizable-se {
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
}

.ui-resizable-nw,
.ui-resizable-sw {
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.ui-resizable-nw,
.ui-resizable-ne {
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.ui-resizable-ne,
.ui-resizable-se {
  margin-right: -1px;
}

.ui-resizable-sw,
.ui-resizable-se {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $('#draggableHelper').draggable().resizable({
    handles: "ne, se, sw, nw"
  });
});
```

This allows the `<img>` to be 100% the size of it's parent and then you can resize the parent. Hope that helps.